# Check table segmentation in Vertica

Tags: vertica

How to check segmentation details of an existing table? I need to retrieve information that were set with `SEGMENTED BY HASH(some_column) ALL NODES` on table creation. I guess it is possible to query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your Vertica version. Since 7.1 there is a column `SEGMENTATION_EXPRESSION` in `V_CATALOG.PROJECTIONS`.